# Analysis of Repeatedly Enciphered Plaintext using Same Algorithm / Key?

Tags: cryptanalysis

Please forgive the impracticality of this question, but I'm curious about the behaviors of encryption algorithms applied to their own output.

Suppose I have an encryption algorithm E and (using the same key(s)) I repeatedly encrypt its output for a given plaintext: `E(E(E(E(...E(plaintext)`

Would a modern encryption algorithm, such as some variant of AES, display any kind of cycling with respect to its output for arbitrarily long compositions of itself?  Is there some known number of compositions where the final output is itself the plaintext?

Comment: You say the question is impractical, but I've actually seen this construction used in real life in KeePass. In their [write up on security](http://keepass.info/help/base/security.html#secdictprotect) they say "KeePass first hashes the user's password using SHA-256, encrypts the result N times using the Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) algorithm (called key transformation rounds from on now), and then hashes it again using SHA-256". They do this to protect against dictionary attacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually, it will cycle, but it'll almost certainly take far longer than your lifetime to do so.

If that sounds too flip, here's the mathematics.  Assuming AES is secure, then the probability it will revisit the original plaintext after at most *r* repeated encryptions is just *r*/2<sup>128</sup>.  (This follows from [a standard fact about the cycle structure of a random permutation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Probability_that_a_random_element_lies_on_a_cycle_of_size_m).)  For the values of *r* that can realistically arise in practice, this probability is negligible: less than the chances of getting hit by lightning, twice.

Is there some known number *r* such that *r* repeated encryptions are guaranteed to bring you back to the plaintext you started with?  Yes, for instance: *r* = (2<sup>128</sup>)!, i.e., 2<sup>128</sup> factorial.  Or, *r* =  lcm(1, 2, 3, ..., 2<sup>128</sup>) also works.   However, this is a stupendously, ridiculously large number.  So it's completely irrelevant in practice.

**Bottom line.** If you've got a secure block cipher, you don't need to worry about cycling.  It's not an issue.  It just ain't gonna happen.

Comment: A clearer way to write your third sentence would be *the probability to reach the original plain text after **at most** r repeated encryptions is r/2^128*.

Comment: Or even more precisely than that: the probability to reach the original plaintext after at most r repeated encryptions is exactly r/2^128 for all r<=2^128 (assuming that the block cipher acts as a random permutation).

Comment: While it is true that (2^128)! is not the minimal number of iterations where you are guaranteed that the output will be the  input (that'd be lcm(1, 2, 3, ..., 2^128)), what is not true is that the birthday paradox applies to iterated AES.  AES is a permutation, not a function; this means that there is 0 probability that, if you haven't seen a repeat yet, that the next output will be a value you've seen before, unless it's the original input.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, everyone.  Three nitpicks: 1. The correct statement of the fact is about the probability of hitting the original plaintext after *exactly* r repeated encryptions, not at most r.  2. Yeah, yeah, yeah.  Fine, so the lcm is smaller than the factorial.  It's still a stupendously, ridiculously, impractically large number.  My conclusion still holds.  3. e501, your statement about 2^64 is not correct.  The birthday paradox is not relevant here.

Comment: @poncho: thanks for pointing that the probability is exact.

Comment: @D.W.: The correct statement is with _at most_ r.

Comment: @fgrieu, quite right!  My mistake.  Sorry about that.  I've updated the answer accordingly.  Thanks for your gentle correction.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Given access to an encryption oracle, the strategy of encrypting the ciphertext repeatedly will eventually lead to a cycle, and the butlast value obtained is the desired plaintext. However this strategy has precisely the same low success odds as trying each plaintext in incremental order and comparing with the ciphertext.

Comment: @D.W. I worked through the math and you are correct about the birthday bound. My apologizes and thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question essentially asks, given a function $f$ that takes an input $i$ of length $k$ and produces an output $o$ of length $k$.

$$i \in \{0, 1\}^k, o \in \{0, 1\}^k $$
$$f(i) = o $$

How many times on average will $f$ have to be recursively called on itself such that it collides with one of it's inputs or outputs (all previous outputs are also inputs).

$$f(f(f(...f(i)...))) = i$$.

Since we are assuming $f$ is a cipher, lets be generous and assume that $f$ randomly maps $i$s to $o$ (that is, lets assume $f$ is secure) such that the same $i$ always produces the same $o$. This is, $f$ is a random permutation over $2^k$ possible $i$s (remember $i$ is a binary number of $k$ digits).

This question really asks:

1. how many times must a permutation on $2^k$ elements be applied to itself such that it repeats [(that is the "order of a permutation")](http://www.math.csusb.edu/notes/advanced/algebra/gp/node7.html)
2. and what is the average order of a random permutation on $2^k$ elements.

The [Landau function](http://oeis.org/A000793) give us the worst possible number of steps we would need to take to get a permeation to repeat itself. This is our upper bound and the answer to question 1.

Question 2 I don't have an exact answer for you but there has been a lot of mathematic work in this area (Paul Erdos worked on this a bit). There is a [mathoverflow question/answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70446/average-over-random-permutations) on the average order of a permutation as well.

Comment: The statements about Question 2, the birthday paradox, and the probability of a collision are not correct.  This is a random permutation, not a random function.  The birthday paradox does not apply.

Comment: P.S. Regarding Question 2: The expectation is (2^128 + 1)/2, per [a standard fact on random permutations](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Expected_cycle_size_of_a_random_element).  This fact about the expectation was on the same page as the fact I linked to in my answer.